# errno 150 mySQL foreign key

Tags: mysql

This SQL is giving me Errno 150 when i'm trying to create the second table with the foreign key on UserID

Can anyone please advice me what am i doing wrong?

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS  OTA;
USE OTA;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users
(
UserID int AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
UserName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
Email varchar(255) UNIQUE ,
PW varchar(255),
PN varchar(255),
Admin BIT
);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Notes
(
UID int AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
Note varchar (255) NOT NULL,
c_Date Date NOT NULL,
c_text varchar (255) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (UID) REFERENCES Persons(UserID)
);
```

Sorry for being a duplicate question but i can't find my answer between the related ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to reference `Persons(UserID)` when your first table is called `Users`. Try this for your key:

```
FOREIGN KEY (UID) REFERENCES Users(UserID)
```

However, you should have a separate column for the note ID.

Comment: Dude i'm sorry for this horrible mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring the primary key after:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(O_Id int NOT NULL,
OrderNo int NOT NULL,
P_Id int,
PRIMARY KEY (O_Id),
FOREIGN KEY (P_Id) REFERENCES Persons(P_Id))
```

Also, you auto-incremented both UID and UserID. This is fine if they are the same length, but if you try to reference a foreign key value that doesn't exist, you will get an error.